# Sum of adjacency matrix of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I really need help to solve this problem since I don´t know where to start:

For A ∈ Mn×n(Z) we define $A^0 = I_n$ (the identity matrix). Let G a graph, prove that G is connected if and ony if exists a r ∈ N such that

$\sum_{i=0}^r A^i_G$

is a matrix with all its entries are different from 0, where $A_G$ is the adjacency matrix of G.

thank you for your time :D.

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: Being honest, I don't know, my "graph and games" teacher gave us a list of problems to solve and this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the fact that a graph is connected if and only if, between any two distinct vertices there exists a path. What is the largest possible length of a path in a graph with $n$ vertices?